# java: simplest way to compare two URLs exluding a parameter

Tags: java, regex, uri

Given two urls, they're considered to be the same if excluding a specific parameter (which may or may not present), they'll be the same.

For example, following urls are the same if parameter that I want to ignore is **p**

```
http://www.a.com/b?c=1&p=1
http://www.a.com/b?c=1
http://www.a.com/b?c=1&p=2
http://www.a.com/b/?c=1&p=3
http://www.a.com/b/?p=4&c=1
http://www.a.com/b/?p=5&c=1&
```

Removing p, these will be

```
http://www.a.com/b?c=1
http://www.a.com/b?c=1
http://www.a.com/b?c=1
http://www.a.com/b/?c=1
http://www.a.com/b/?c=1
http://www.a.com/b/?c=1
```

which are the same

What's the simplest way to do this? I feel that it's overkill to construct an uri, remove specific parameter, then call toString for comparison. Thanks.

Comment: The last two have an extra slash.

Comment: Your question only mentions you want to ignore `p`.

Comment: edit question for clarity. The same doesnt mean literal strings are the same.

Comment: So are you trying to strip the slash or not? If you're trying to use string comparison, it doesn't matter whether you consider them the same, it matters whether they have the same characters.

Comment: And there's a trailing ampersand in the last one.

Comment: Still the same url. I don't know how I can be clearer :( Two urls are the same if protocol, domain (all levels), port, authority are the same, and all parameters are the same regardless of order.

Comment: I intentionally add extra / and & in examples to make it clear.

Comment: I get that it's the same URL. But if you want to treat it as a URL, you can't evaluate it as a string! You'll need to use a URL parser or write a custom method.

Comment: Yes, I can use URI to achieve this but I think it's overkill and was looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Well it doesn't exist.

Comment: This question is much harder than it sounds. Constructing a URL object would be the easiest place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "blablable....";
String url_without_p;

int p_index = url.indexOf("p=");
if (p_index == -1) 
{
    url_without_p = url;
}
else 
{
    int end_index = url.indexOf("&", p_index);
    if (end_index == -1)
    {
        url_without_p = url.substring(0, p_index);
    }
    else
    {
       url_without_p = url.substring(0, p_index) + url.substring(end_index);
    }
}
return url_without_p;
```

Comment: regex may be a simpler option. Not faster though

Comment: Simply removing p is not enough since parameters can be in any order. Say I have a=1&b=2  and b=2&a=1. p isn't even in the url but comparing literal strings will fail.

Comment: the code above doesn't care about the position of p. try it. It even works if p is not present

Comment: The code only removes p. I thought you suggested to remove p and then compare two strings, which doesn't solve my problem. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: You ask for: "considered to be the same if excluding a specific parameter". Just choose what parameter to exclude, execute the code and compare the result with the other url you want to compare it.